# Counting number of subarrays that satisifies the given property.

Tags: combinatorics

Given an array A having n elements and a number K,I want to count the number of subarrays(i.e Elements need to be contiguous) of A, such that no 2 elements in the subarray holds the property A[i]%A[j]==K.(i must be less than j)
For example say n=3 and k=2 and the given array as 5,3,1.
Answer will be 4 as there are 6 total subarrays of A out of which {5,3} and {5,3,1} are not allowed.
I can generate all possibilities and count but i guess there is some better mathematical approach to this question and thus i am looking for some sort of formula to do this...

Answer (score 0):

This is a special case of [Finding number of subarrays not including certain pairs](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1393375), to which [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1394000) that was given is, I believe, about as good an answer as you'll get.