# Finding number of subarrays not including certain pairs

Tags: combinatorics, number-theory, algorithms, computer-science, combinations

How many contiguous subarrays of an array exist such that they do not contain certain pairs of positions of the array?
For eg. if array ={11,22,33,45}
and if we do not want to include say position number (1,3) and (2,4)  then number of contiguous subarrays that exist are 7 which are as follows {{11},{22},{33},{44},{11,22},{22,33},{33,45}}.

My attempt at solving the problem:

If two pairs exist such that {...,a1, ...,a2 ,..,b1, ..,b2} 
where n is the number of elemnts and (...) indicate that there are elements in between these positions.

1st case :We cannot include {a1,b1} and {a2,b2} then we have to just count the number of possible combinations which is n*(n+1)/2 - no. of possible combinations including {a2,b1} which covers all the possible

case 2. If we cannot include pairs {a1,b2} and {a2,b1} then we just subtract number of possibilties containing {a2,b1} which covers all the possible cases.

3rd case: if we can't include pairs {a1,a2} and {b1,b2} then we have to individually subtract possible subarrays including these positions

The problem I'm facing is I am not able to derive a formula and extend these cases to more than 2 pairs to count the number of possible solutions even after formulating the cases. So, I need help regarding that.

Source: This is an interview question asked to my friend which he could not answer.

Answer (score 3):

It is hard to achieve a simple formula. Maybe using inclusion-exclusion principle can be possible, but I don't think that's a good idea. If I were your friend, I would answer this:

Let's define a subarray $[i..j]$ is *valid* when there are no invalid pairs inside it. Also let's denote the array's size as $n$, and the indexes are integers from 1 to $N$.

Some (maybe obvious) facts:

- If $[i..j]$ is valid, $[(i+1)..j]$ and $[i..(j-1)]$ are also valid too.
- If $[i..j]$ is *not* valid, $[i..(j+1)]$, $[i..(j+2)]$, ..., $[i..n]$ are also *not* valid too.

Let's define $r_i$ as the rightmost index where $[i..r_i]$ is valid. With these two facts, we can conclude that $r_1 \le r_2 \le \cdots \le r_{n}$ ($\{r_{i}\}$ is monotonically increasing) So using the [two pointers](http://codeforces.com/blog/entry/4586) method, we can get $r_{i}$ for all possible $i$.

Then, it is easy to get the answer: $\sum_{i=1}^{n} (r_{i} - i + 1)$.